# Heroku- Error log uninitialized constant Admin (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, namespaces

I am trying to host my application on Heroku,my app is successfully building, but throwing an unrelated error at runtime.please help me solve this error.

**heroku logs:**
2017-11-28T23:29:01.319086+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/Admin/dependents_controller.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant Admin (NameError.

I am using Ruby On Rails and Devise for Admin related stuff,following are my related files.

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do
root :to => 'home#index'  
resources :dependents
end
```

**app/controllers/admin/dependents_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::DependentsController < ApplicationController
end
```

**app/views/admin/dependents**

this have all my dependents related views

current heroku logs after doing changes

**Heroku Logs(current)**

```
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014769+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014768+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014769+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014770+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014777+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014778+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014779+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014779+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014780+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014783+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014784+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014785+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014792+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014793+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014794+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014794+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014795+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:in `new'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014798+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014796+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:in `<main>'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014796+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014797+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014798+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014799+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014799+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014800+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014801+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014801+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014802+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014802+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014803+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014803+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014804+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014805+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014805+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014806+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014806+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014807+00:00 app[web.1]:  from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.014808+00:00 app[web.1]:  from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-11-29T11:11:11.215542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-11-29T11:11:11.203657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-11-29T16:39:09.572143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-11-29T16:39:14.954266+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 6004 -e production`
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078728+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078767+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production 
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078768+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078775+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078867+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/Admin/dependents_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Admin (NameError)
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078878+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078879+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078879+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078882+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078889+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078899+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078900+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078903+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078903+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078904+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `each'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078905+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078905+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078906+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078906+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078911+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078909+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078909+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078942+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078912+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078944+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078947+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078948+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078949+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078959+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078946+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078948+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078949+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078960+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078962+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078963+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078964+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:in `new'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078965+00:00 app[web.1]:  from config.ru:in `<main>'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078984+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078986+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078988+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078989+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.078990+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079011+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079010+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079013+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079014+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079030+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079032+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079033+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079035+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079036+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079038+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079055+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079057+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079058+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079060+00:00 app[web.1]:  from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.079082+00:00 app[web.1]:  from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-11-29T16:39:23.261492+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-11-29T16:39:23.274795+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark. This part:

```
/app/app/controllers/Admin/dependents_controller.rb:1
```

seems curious because it seems to indicate that your `admin` (should be lower case) directory is actually named `Admin` (appears to be upper case).

Are your directory names correct?

Comment: Great!! I renamed to "admin" and deployed in heroku, but still it is giving me Application error :(

Comment: Same error? If different, please update your original question. BTW, you *might* consider setting `config.eager_load = true` in `config/environments/development.rb` which *might* help you catch uninitialized constant errors (and others) before deploying to Heroku.

Comment: I updated the question with current logs.please check into it and give me a solution.that would be really helpful.

Comment: Curiously, it still says `/app/app/controllers/Admin/dependents_controller.rb:1` (with *A*dmin). I don't know if that's your problem (might not be), but that looks unconventional.

Comment: Yes!! it is still saying same.Even after I renamed the folder , I don't understand whats the problem is.